# Passing byte[] as IntPtr by PInvoke to memset

Tags: c#, pinvoke, memset, intptr

I need to pass a byte array to memset, which due to P/Invoke clunkiness takes IntPtr. Tested by hand, it works, but I am seeking theoretical confirmation. Is this method correct?

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memset", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern IntPtr MemSet(IntPtr dest, int c, int count);

static unsafe void ZeroMemset (byte[] data)
{
    fixed (byte* bytes = data) {
        MemSet ((IntPtr)bytes, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no "chunkiness".  Your mistake was not declaring the *dest* argument the logical way.  It should be `byte[]`.  Remove additional chunkiness by declaring the 2nd argument the normal way as well, `byte`.  The non-chunky pinvoke marshaller takes care of everything else.

Comment: I meant clunkiness, a mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @Hans The second parameter is `int`: `void *memset( void *dest, int c, size_t count );`

Comment: No, only the low byte of the int gets used.  The pinvoke marshaller does not need help promoting a byte to int.

Comment: @Hans I thought you were implying that `int` was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and will work correctly.

It would be perfectly reasonable, and much clearer in my view, to avoid `unsafe` and declare the parameter to `memset` to be `byte[]`. I'd declare it like this:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr memset(byte[] dest, int c, IntPtr count);
```

Note that the final parameter is `size_t` which is pointer sized.

I also do wonder why you are opting to do this at all in unmanaged code, but presumably you have your reasons.

Comment: PInvoke signature came from pinvoke.net. I am testing performance of different methods, with native memset being one of them.

Comment: You can declare it with `byte[]` for convenience. I can't see that being bettered.